# How to know what data type an operation will return in C++

Tags: c++, c, types, floating-point, int

Is there a general rule to know whether the result of an operation will be, for example, an int or a float, in C++ when there is a mixture of data types in the operation.

Comment: [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)?

Comment: you mean apart from reading the declaration of the function you're calling?

Comment: I think they mean the arithmetic operators.

Comment: I didn't mean in a function. Something like (int + float) / int = ? Is there a way to know what operations of similar structures will return just by looking at them?